# How to add registry to 64bit area through Install Script function?

Tags: registry, installshield, installscript

Many of InstallShield developers has a doubt of how to add **registry to 64 bit area** using IstallScript function in InstallShield.

If our installer is 32bit EXE, and if we are installing this installer on 64 bit machine, then all RegDB functions points to **Wow6432Node** registry area. But many of times we have to add registry to 64 bit area using 32 bit installer. So how we can achieve this ?

For e.g.
If I'm executing following code in InstallScript.

```
RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
RegDBCreateKeyEx("SOFTWARE\\XYZ", "");
```

I want to add this registry entry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\XYZ`. But this entry gets added under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XYZ`.

Then what is the solution to add this registry under 64 bit area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to achieve this scenario.

**First solution** is,

We can create component, make it 64 bit and we will add registry entry under it in InstallShield.

**Second solution** is,

If we want to add registry which is independent of any component then we can use `REGDB_OPTIONS`.

```
RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;
RegDBCreateKeyEx("SOFTWARE\\XYZ", "");
```

This will add registry to 64 bit area.